# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'path' plis ayuda

Tags: python, tkinter

quiero que el file_root salga en entry
ya intente con insert
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'path'

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, LEFT
from tkinter import filedialog
class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.add_components()
        self.root.mainloop()
    @staticmethod
    def change_path(self):
        file_root = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select File",filetypes = (("Python3 file","*.py"),("Others","*.*")))
        self.path.set(file_root)#el path obtenida por el file root aparesca en el entry
    def add_components(self):
        self.path = tk.Entry(self.root, state="readonly")
        self.path.bind("<1>", self.change_path)
        self.path.pack(side=LEFT)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplication()
```

Comment: Why did you declare `change_path` as a `@staticmethod`? Remove that and also change `def change_path(self)` to `def change_path(self, event)`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post in English.

Comment: You can post in Spanish at [es.so].

Comment: As you declared `change_path()` a static method, the first argument pass to it will be the event object, not the class instance.

Comment: if you use `@staticmethod` then you should use `def change_path(vent)` without `self` - so you can't use `self.path` inside this functiona. And you should assing it as `Aplication.change_path`. Better create it without `@staticmethod`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me

Comment: I try to tell you that you mix two different methods - `staticmethod` can't use `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix two different methods - `staticmethod` can't use `self` because it doesn't get it.

You should write it without `@staticmethod`

There are other problems.

`Entry` doesn't have `.set(text)` but `.insert('end', text)

I can't set text when it is readonly (at least on my Linux it doesn't work) and I have to switch to `normal`, set text, switch to `readonly`

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.add_components()
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def change_path(self, event):
        print('event:', event)
        file_root = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File", filetypes=(("Python3 file","*.py"),("Others","*.*")))
        #print(file_root)
        self.path['state'] = 'normal'
        self.path.insert('end', file_root)
        self.path['state'] = 'readonly'
        
    def add_components(self):
        self.path = tk.Entry(self.root, state="readonly")
        self.path.bind("<1>", self.change_path)
        self.path.pack(side='left')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplication()
```